# Using jquery datatables in alfresco 5

Tags: jquery, datatables, dojo, alfresco-share

I'm facing some problems while trying to setup [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin (a jQuery plugin to enhance html tables)  in a surf page in alfresco 5.

Alfresco 5 uses dojo as a base of some components.I don't have too much understanding of dojo ,but it seems that dojo loads among other thing some version of jQuery.

[image: resources tree link here]

That version of jQuery enters in conflict with  the jQuery  included in datatables library and i am getting  errors like *multipleDefine* ( $ function i guess)  and *Cannot set property '$' of undefined*.

I have tried to use a version of datatables without embedded jQuery to use the one provided by dojo but it doesn't work.

How could i manage to  avoid that collisions ? Is there a proper way to make datatables work with dojo?

Comment: Try loading DataTables without jQuery and include DataTables resources AFTER loading all dojo resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it. I used dojo loader to load datatables resource like this:

require(["https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.js"], function(){
   $(document).ready(function(){var table = $('#tasktable').DataTable();
    } );

});